# run-p: command not found

Tags: node.js, express, npm

after installing 'npm install webpack-dev-server -g'
not able to start expressjs project.

I am using below script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "run-p watch dev-server",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode development",
    "dev-server": "BABEL_ENV=dev nodemon --exec 'babel-node' src/server/index.js --config nodemon.json"
}
```

Comment: [Webpack doesn't provide a `run-p` command.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server#with-npm-scripts) Are you missing another dependency – perhaps [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all#cli-commands)?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Install/add [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)

```
npm i npm-run-all --save-dev
```

Comment: even better, `npm i npm-run-all -D` and then add `run-p: npm run run-p` to your `package.json`.`scripts` section

Answer (score 7):

Run

`npm install npm-run-all --save-dev`

So that `npm-run-all` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all
is saved into package.json as dev dependency (so that other developers don't get the same problem)

Docs https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the correct folder path in the terminal. Check it once and move to the correct project folder and run the desired command

Answer (score 0):

I had `npm-run-all` in my *package.json > "devDependencies"* but still was getting the same error:

> 'npm-run-all' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

The solution was to install it globally using the following command:

```
npm i npm-run-all -g
```